# I have bytes in use at exit but can't seem to make out where exactly. (cs50, pset5)

Tags: c, valgrind, cs50

I just completed the cs50 pset 5 [speller](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/#:%7E:text=help50%20valgrind%20./speller%20texts/cat.txt) code. It isn't perfect and efficient yet but I first want to make it work. The code spell-checks text from given dictionary. The program runs as expected. I used valgrind on it to check for memory leaks and it says the following

```
==12518== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12518== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12518== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12518== Command: ./speller texts/lalaland.txt
==12518== 
==12518== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12518==    at 0x524A071: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1021)
==12518==    by 0x52562E5: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:34)
==12518==    by 0x4011FC: load (dictionary.c:67)
==12518==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==12518==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12518==    at 0x401194: load (dictionary.c:59)
==12518== 
==12518== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==12518==    at 0x5246FDD: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1103)
==12518==    by 0x52562E5: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:34)
==12518==    by 0x4011FC: load (dictionary.c:67)
==12518==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==12518==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12518==    at 0x401194: load (dictionary.c:59)
==12518== 
==12518== 
==12518== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12518==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x51DF0E8
==12518==    at 0x5246FDD: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1103)
==12518==    by 0x52562E5: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:34)
==12518==    by 0x4011FC: load (dictionary.c:67)
==12518==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==12518== 
==12518== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12518==     in use at exit: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==12518==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 4,648 bytes allocated
==12518== 
==12518== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==12518==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12518==    by 0x5258E49: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==12518==    by 0x5258E49: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==12518==    by 0x4011B1: load (dictionary.c:60)
==12518==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==12518== 
==12518== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12518==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12518==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12518==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12518==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
==12518==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12518== 
==12518== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12518== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

I am a beginner coder and what I understood from this is I didn't free 552 bytes somewhere. Below is my code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 5000;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

int words = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int x = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[x];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp (cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        char a;
        a = toupper(word[i]);
        x += a;
    }
    return x;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Dictionary couldn't be opened\n");
        return false;
    }
    char *word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", *word) != EOF)
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            printf("Out of memory.\n");
            return false;
        }
        strcpy (n->word, *word);
        n->next = NULL;
        int x = hash(*word);
        if (table[x] == NULL)
        {
            table[x] = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = table[x];
            table[x] = n;
        }
        words++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] != NULL)
        {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        node *tmp = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Also side note, I ran check50 to check if it works fine but it did not pass, I got [this result](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/766ea02e8f6d37f9a484551aab8be8d23e6f212a). I'm guessing it's related to the memory leak but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your program isn't exiting, it is getting terminated with a segfault. Fix that before looking for possible leaks

Comment: @Mat when running the program normally it doesn't show any segmentation fault. It does exit

Comment: A segfault is usually the result of *undefined behavior*, which means you may or may not get it on your local machine (or only in specific cases, or....)

Comment: `while (fscanf(file, "%s", *word) != EOF)` = recipe for disaster when `*word` resolves to an *indeterminate* pointer (which is exactly what you're doing). I'm highly suspicious that should be `char word[LENGTH + 1];` and `while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)` , changing all the other `*word` later as warranted.

Comment: Your program crashed. It never got to `free` because it crashed. The memory leak is not the problem, the crash is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look through the logs, they actually have very useful information. It tells me that you are referencing an uninitialized value. In fact, this probably leads to the SEGFAULT. This is confirmed in the log:

```
==12518== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

Let's see how I could figure this out. The relevant part of the logs are:

```
==12518== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12518==    at 0x524A071: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1021)
==12518==    by 0x52562E5: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:34)
==12518==    by 0x4011FC: load (dictionary.c:67)
==12518==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
==12518==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==12518==    at 0x401194: load (dictionary.c:59)
```

The first part of this log is a backtrace. It shows the order of function calls leading to the error. In this case, `main` called `load` which called `<something>_fscanf`. The rest of the backtrace is for internal calls within `libc` which implements `fscanf`. This tells us *where* the error is. It also tells me *what* the error is: the program uses a value without initializing it.

Now, let us look at the relevant line in the `load` function:

```
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", *word) != EOF) { ... }
```

Of these, I can see that `file` is properly initialized by calling `fopen` and checking for a null return value. The second argument is a constant string. Therefore, the third argument is the problem. Let us see where it is declared.

Now, looking at the previous line, you see that `word` is declared as `char *word[]` which is *an array of char pointers*. I guess what you actually wanted was *a pointer to a char array*. The proper declaration should be `char word[LENGTH + 1]`. In the current form, it is an array of pointers. These pointers have not been initialized in this function, so might actually contain `LENGTH + 1` null pointers. Further, due to stack reuse (see how stack frames work), this array might contain other random garbage, which might include actual pointers (and lead to state corruption). In fact, this is exactly what happens. Let us go back to the logs:

```
==12518== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12518==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x51DF0E8
```

The uninitialized pointer held the value `0x51df0e8`, and `fscanf` probably tried to write to this address, encountering a segmentation fault since the pointer is actually invalid.

Finally, let us look at the last part of the log:

```
==12518== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12518==     in use at exit: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
```

This tells us that some allocated heap memory was not freed. This is a result of your segmentation fault. The `malloc` was executed, but not the corresponding `free` since the program crashed in between.

In conclusion, I would like to stress that it is useful to read and interpret the logs, which contains a lot of useful information. Further, I would also recommend that you learn to use a debugger like `gdb` which would allow you to quickly and precisely identify problems in your programs, and which will become *essential* as your programs grow. Bon coding, chef...

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I'm new to valgrind so I couldn't understand most of the logs but your explanation has made it very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully `LENGTH` is defined in `dictionary.h` and is longer than any word in file

```
char word[LENGTH + 1]; // not char *word[LENGTH + 1];
```

Remember to `close(file)` before returning.

```
size_t table_index = x % N; //need table_index between 0 and N-1
```

Remember to zero the table at the start if you change the way it's declared.